# Intersection with non-empty compacts

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove the following implication (I think the "proof" is flawed, but have no better idea)

Suppose that $\{ K_i \subset R^d|K_i \; is\;compact\;and\;K_i \not=\emptyset\;,i\in N \}$ and $K \subset R^d$ is also a compact set. Show that if $\forall\;U\subset R^d, U\;is\; open:(K\cap U\not = \emptyset \implies \exists i_0\in N\;\forall i\in N,\;i_0 \leq i:K_i \cap U\not=\emptyset)$ then
$\forall x \in K\;\exists\{x_i\}:N\rightarrow\bigcup_{i\in N}K_i\;s.t.\forall i\in N:x_i\in K_i \;and\;x_i \rightarrow x$

My attempt goes:

Suppose $x \in K$ is arbitrary then $B(x,1)$ is open and $B(x,1)\cap K\not=\emptyset$ thus $\exists i_0^1 \in N \;\forall i\in N,\;i_0^1 \leq i:K_i \cap B(x,1)\not=\emptyset$ and thus $\forall i \in N,\;i_0^1 \leq i\; \exists x_i^1 \in K_i\; s.t.\;||x-x_i^1||<1$ Since $K_i \not= \emptyset$ we can choose arbitrary $x_i \in K_i\;i=1,...,i_0^1-1$ Now suppose we have constructed sequences $\{x_i^1\},...,\{x_i^n\}$ where $n \in N$ Then $B(x,\frac{1}{n+1})\cap K\not=\emptyset$ thus $\exists i_0^{n+1} \in N \;\forall i\in N,\;i_0^{n+1} \leq i:K_i \cap B(x,\frac{1}{n+1})\not=\emptyset$ and so $\forall i \in N,\;i_0^{n+1} \leq i\; \exists x_i^{n+1} \in K_i\; s.t.\;||x-x_i^{n+1}||<\frac{1}{n+1}$ By mathematical induction we've constructed sequence of sequences.

Now fix $i \in N$ Since $K_i$ is compact and $\{x_i^n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequnce in this set it has a convergent subsequence $\{x_i^{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ with limit $x^i \in K_i$ Now I am not sure whether this is true, but I'd like to show that $x^i \rightarrow x$

Suppose $i,k \in N$ are arbitrary, then $||x^i-x||=||x^i-x_i^{n_k}+x_i^{n_k}-x||\leq||x^i-x_i^{n_k}||+||x_i^{n_k}-x||$ by the triangle inequality. Then $\lim_{k\to\infty}||x^i-x||\leq0+\lim_{k\to\infty}||x_i^{n_k}-x||$ Then $\lim_{i\to\infty}||x^i-x||\leq\lim_{i\to\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}||x_i^{n_k}-x||$ Here I would like to swap the limits but am not sure if I can do that. If I could then $\lim_{i\to\infty}||x^i-x||\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{i\to\infty}||x_i^{n_k}-x||\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}\lim_{i\to\infty}\frac{1}{n_k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{n_k}=0$ and therefore $\lim_{i\to\infty}||x^i-x||=0$ and it would be complete.

Thank you for pointing out any mistakes and making suggestions :)